# how to match a list of selected bigrams and a list of toknised tweets dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nltk, tokenize

i have a list of selected bigrams like this:

```
[['arizona amp', 'says despite', 'aims watch', 'online able',
  'completely way', 'samsung throw', 'breaking vs', 'mobile free', 
  'away market', 'microsoft rolled', 'wireless insurance', 'launches booster', 
  'rt selling', 'glass related', 'new challenges', 'share fighting',
  'wireless cream', 'free store', 'beat drone']
```

i want to matched with a list of dictionaries of tokenized tweets like this:

```
[ ({'google': True, 'nasa might': True, 'google nasa': True,
    'washington': True, 'drone mars': True, 'washington post': True, 
    'mars washington': True, 'drone': True, 'put drone': True, 'mars': True, 
    'put': True, 'post': True, 'might put': True, 'might': True, 'nasa': True}, 'co'),
 ({'first metal': True, 'launches first': True, 'metal smartphone': True,  
    'smartphone': True, 'samsung': True, 'iphone6': True, 'launches': True, 
    'metal': True, 'samsung launches': True, 'take': True, 'take iphone6': True, 
    'smartphone take': True, 'first': True}, 'co')]
```

the task is to iterate over each tokenized tweet and keep only the bigrams that exist in selected bigram list
can you help me to find a function does that

Comment: IIUC, try "[[k for k in x[0].keys() if k in in_list] for x in tweets]" , but as far as I see none of the tokens are in the llst

Comment: this is just an example

Comment: this doesint keep the structure of the tweets. i want to just delete any bigrams that not in the list and keep ather tokens with its values as a dict